# Do different cat breeds need different kinds of food?

Tags: cats

I love cats so I take special care of them. A few days ago, my uncle gifted me a Persian cat, but the problem is that she does not eat as normal cats eat their food. I'm a little bit afraid that she may have gotten ill, and winter has arrived so it is more important to take special care of her.

Comment: it is a little hard to understand your question,sometimes it can take some time to find a food your cat likes.you can try canned tuna flavored cat food but if the cat do not eat soon you have to take it to a vet as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Your best simple bet is to ask your uncle what the cat was eating before it was given to you and buy some of that.  Many cats have a hard time with change, and the change to a new home and new food at the same time is likely too much for her to process all at once.  Besides, changing foods or feeding schedule suddenly can cause stomach upset in some cats.

Try returning to whatever food she was eating before, and then once she's been eating normally a while, gradually transition to the food you want her to eat long term, by replacing a little more of the old brand of food with the new brand each day.  You should do this slowly over several days, or even several weeks if the cat is very sensitive.

If going back to her original food brand doesn't do the trick right away, you should have her checked by the vet; cats can go only a short time without eating before they get very ill.